# What to call a term-in-context whose context contains exactly the variables occurring in the term?

Tags: terminology, proof-theory, type-theory

In type theory, a term-in-context
$\Gamma \vdash t : \tau $
is only well-formed when $\Gamma$ contains all the variables occurring in $t:\tau$. Is there a name for when it contains exactly the variables occurring in $t:\tau$?

Comment: I don't know of any such adjective. However the process of removing an unused (set of) variables from the context is called Thinning or Strengthening. So you could build a superlative based on that, I guess.

Comment: "strong" or "thin" sound ok to me